# Pattern Matching using REGEXP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to make a column in mysql called `group` if from the second through the third position of the string matches exactly `07`. For instance, the string `a07ha` should be categorized as `07` since this satisfies the condition. This gives me an error. I guess I'm messed up with the `= '07'` part. Any advice would be of great help.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 'a07ha' REGEXP '^{2,3}' = '07' THEN '07'
    ELSE '00'
END AS group
```

Comment: I would suggest that it would be better to make a group field that contains OLNY the group code and nothing else

Comment: `REGEXP` doesn't return the matching part, it just returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Also, your regexp doesn't match characters 2-3. It returns the last 2-3 characters because the `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Why not just use `SUBSTR(column, 2, 2)`?

Comment: You can't use `{2,3}` without a pattern before it. It means 2-3 repetitions of the preceding pattern.

Comment: you need to read a regular expression tutorial, you seem to be making bad assumptions about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described your condition:

> if from the second through the third position of the string matches exactly `07`.

The `{2,3}` pattern does not need to be used for this. All you need to check that the literal characters `07` follow the first character.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'a07ha' REGEXP '^.07' THEN '07' ELSE '00' END AS `group`
```